# Concentration bound for a probability recursion

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $m$ be a natural number, $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $\tau$ be some real number.

Consider the following sequence of random variables $\delta_0 = 0, \delta_1, \delta_2, \dots, \delta_T$ where
\begin{align*}
\delta_{t+1} = \begin{cases}
  (1-\lambda)\delta_{t-1} & \text{w.p. } 1-1/m \\
  (1-\lambda)\delta_{t-1} + \tau & \text{w.p. } 1/m
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

It is easy to see that the expectation of $\delta_T$ is bounded by $\frac{\tau}{m\lambda}$. My question is whether one can obtain a good concentration bound for $\delta_T$.

One easy idea (but does not seem to be very good) is to consider the following sequence of independent random variables $X_1, \dots, X_T$ where
$X_i = 0$ with probability $1 - 1/m$ and $\tau(1-\lambda)^{T-i}$ with probability $1/m$. Define $X = \sum_{i=1}^TX_i$. It is easy to see that $X = \delta_T$. Then one can scale each $X_i$ to a $0$-$1$ random variable by dividing it by $\tau(1-\lambda)^{T-i}$ and apply for example Chernoff bound. However the result seems very rough..

Any reference for such kind of problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt I tried. Actually it is not very hopeful to derive strong concentrations because the expectation is $\frac{\tau}{m\lambda}$, while with probability $1/m$ we will have $\tau$ already.

But here is a way to get something. Divide $X_1, \dots, X_T$ into two segments $X_1, \dots, X_l$, and $X_{l+1}, \dots, X_T$ where $l = m - c\ln m$ where $c$ is some constant. Therefore the contribution of $X_1 + \cdots +X_l$ is bounded by $(1-\lambda)^{T-l}\frac{\tau}{\lambda} = (1-\lambda)^{c\ln m}\frac{\tau}{\lambda} = \frac{\tau}{\lambda m^{c\lambda}}$. The tail has no contribution with probability $(1 - \frac{1}{m})^{c\ln m} \approx 1 - \frac{c\ln m}{m}$. Therefore we have that with probability at least $1 - \frac{c\ln m}{m}$ that $\delta_T$ is bounded by $\frac{\tau}{\lambda m^{c\lambda}}$.